# cocos2d setasedge issue

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

In cocos2d version v1.0.1

```
        groundBox.SetAsEdge(left,right);
```

It needs to not use the SetAsEdge as an error saying that the method doesn't exist, which makes sense as it was removed in a previous version 
However I'm unsure of how to do this as its not creating a box and I'm unsure instead its creating multiple lines using an array of vertexs (from my understanding) how do I do it using the new

```
- (void)createGroundEdgesWithVerts:(b2Vec2 *)verts numVerts:(int)num 
                   spriteFrameName:(NSString *)spriteFrameName {
    CCSprite *ground = 
    [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteFrameName];
    ground.position = ccp(groundMaxX+ground.contentSize.width/2, 
                          ground.contentSize.height/2);
    [groundSpriteBatchNode addChild:ground];

    b2PolygonShape groundShape;  

    b2FixtureDef groundFixtureDef;
    groundFixtureDef.shape = &groundShape;
    groundFixtureDef.density = 0.0;

    // Define the ground box shape.
    b2PolygonShape groundBox;       

    for(int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i) {
        b2Vec2 offset = b2Vec2(groundMaxX/PTM_RATIO + 
                               ground.contentSize.width/2/PTM_RATIO, 
                               ground.contentSize.height/2/PTM_RATIO);
        b2Vec2 left = verts[i] + offset;
        b2Vec2 right = verts[i+1] + offset;

        groundShape.SetAsEdge(left,right);

        groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundFixtureDef);    
    }

    groundMaxX += ground.contentSize.width;
}
```

Comment: you are talking about box2d instead of cocos2d

Comment: yeah well technically its both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is box2d.  In the newer version I believe there is a class called b2EdgeShape and it has a method called Set()  You could use that instead of the polygon shape and its deprecated setEdge method.

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

See section 4.5

Answer (score 2):

You could check how the new Cocos2D+Box2D sample project does it.

Here's how I create a screen-sized box in [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com):

```
    // for the screenBorder body we'll need these values
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    float widthInMeters = screenSize.width / PTM_RATIO;
    float heightInMeters = screenSize.height / PTM_RATIO;
    b2Vec2 lowerLeftCorner = b2Vec2(0, 0);
    b2Vec2 lowerRightCorner = b2Vec2(widthInMeters, 0);
    b2Vec2 upperLeftCorner = b2Vec2(0, heightInMeters);
    b2Vec2 upperRightCorner = b2Vec2(widthInMeters, heightInMeters);

    // Define the static container body, which will provide the collisions at screen borders.
    b2BodyDef screenBorderDef;
    screenBorderDef.position.Set(0, 0);
    b2Body* screenBorderBody = world->CreateBody(&screenBorderDef);
    b2EdgeShape screenBorderShape;

    // Create fixtures for the four borders (the border shape is re-used)
    screenBorderShape.Set(lowerLeftCorner, lowerRightCorner);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
    screenBorderShape.Set(lowerRightCorner, upperRightCorner);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
    screenBorderShape.Set(upperRightCorner, upperLeftCorner);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
    screenBorderShape.Set(upperLeftCorner, lowerLeftCorner);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
```

Comment: how do you set the color for that? to transparent preferably